# Brunch/Breakfast: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'frontend/js/components/Hello' from 'frontend/js/app.js'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vuejs2, vue-component, brunch

I'm having this error in the browser console:

`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'frontend/js/components/Hello' from 'frontend/js/app.js'`

when following through [vue example](http://breakfast.devlocker.io/examples/vue.html) in breakfast documentaton to setup Rails with Vuejs

I cant figure it out what's missing, when I look in the loaded assets into the browser I can see components/hello is not being generated?

Any Ideas of what configuration is missing in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one follow the instructions as here http://breakfast.devlocker.io/examples/vue.html wont be able to make it work. It's missing the following:

1. Create directory `assets` under `/public` directory before firing up the `rails s` command
2. Import MUST be capitalized if your file is `app/frontend/components/Hello.vue`. So in `app.js` put:
   `import Hello from './components/Hello';` instead of
   `import Hello from './components/hello';`
3. You MUST add this to the

`brunch-fonfig.js`

```
module.exports = {
files: {
  javascripts: {
    joinTo: {
      'app.js': /^app\/frontend\/js\//,
      'vendor.js': /^(?!app\/frontend\/js)/
    }
  },
  stylesheets: {
    joinTo: 'app.css'
  },
  templates: {    <<============ MISSING THING!
    joinTo: {
      'app.js': 'app/frontend/js/components/*.vue'
    }
  }
},
...rest of file
```

More info on second issue here https://github.com/nblackburn/vue-brunch/issues/5

I have created a repo with a Rails boilerplate having Rails 5 + Brunch + vue working [here](https://github.com/jgonzalezd/rails_5_boilerplate/tree/breakfast_vue)